# Im trying to click on a ui button but the cursor goes into the camera and disappears

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to click on a ui button but the cursor goes into the camera and disappears
video for reference -> https://youtu.be/QmF9lwbkuCw

Comment: I am on a school laptop and your video is blocked here. Could you please attach additional information and I can surely help you out with that?

Comment: sure if this link is blocked [Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/P7igfdc) 
i pasted the code into the github thing
[git](https://github.com/maxallen05/maxallen05/blob/main/the%20code%20oooOoOoOoOO)

Answer (score 0):

can you post your code please, in the meantime I'd assume it has something to do with `Cursor.lockState` and `Cursor.visible` so if you wanted to debug it you can try these in void Start/Awake

```
//to lock in the centre of window
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
//to hide the curser
Cursor.visible = false;
```

Comment: I was using those statements in my code before but I will try seeing if there being called correctly [link](https://imgur.com/a/P7igfdc)